# Modifying AccessDenied.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a website I didn't build. As far as I understand, AccessDenied.aspx comes with some default behaviour, such as the default error message for a failed login attempt is ''Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.'

I want to change the message conditionally so it shows a different message if they have exhausted their login attempts.

I have some code in AccessDenied.aspx: `<asp:Literal ID="msgFailedLogin" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>`

When I try to access the fields from AccessDenied.aspx.cs using 
`msgFailedLogin.InnerText = "New text";` 
the compiler tells me 
`msgFailedLogin does not exist in current context`.

I am able to access it using 
`((Literal)Login1.FindControl("msgFailedLogin")).Text = "New text";`

Is there some built in behaviour interfering with my attempt to access this field using the typical convention of `<id>.<method/property>`?

I would include more code but none of it seems to be relevant.

Comment: Don't include `Tags` in Title !!!

Comment: Can you access other fields directly?  Maybe something is wrong with the code-behind declaration.

Comment: @bmm6o No I can't access anything by the id alone. The only thing that seems to work is the way I mentioned above casting the control after finding it.